# Cron job is not performing the expected task

Tags: linux, cron, command-line-interface, backup

I set up a cron job to start Restic in order to backup data.
The cron job seems running but it doesn't perfom any tasks apparently.

There is the cron job below in etc/crontab

```
vim /etc/crontab
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed

59  *  *  *  * root . ~/.restic.env ; /usr/local/bin/restic backup --files-from=/root/restic.files --tag automated 2>> ~/restic.err >> ~/restic.log
```

I did  systemctl restart crond after having modified the file in /etc/crontab

The files restic.err and restic.log are empty

The command restic snapshots doesn't show any new entries since I init the repository.

Output for tail - f /var/log/cron

```
Oct 14 09:10:01 vm1 CROND[11862]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 14 09:20:01 vm1 CROND[11968]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 14 09:22:01 vm1 CROND[12004]: (root) CMD (. ~/.restic.env ; /usr/local/bin/restic backup --files-from=/root/restic.files --tag automated 2>> ~/restic.err >> ~/restic.log)
Oct 14 09:30:01 vm1 CROND[12091]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 14 09:40:01 vm1 CROND[12197]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 14 09:50:01 vm1 CROND[12304]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 14 09:58:37 vm1 crond[5026]: (CRON) INFO (Shutting down)
Oct 14 09:58:37 vm1 crond[12493]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 26% if used.)
Oct 14 09:58:37 vm1 crond[12493]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Oct 14 09:58:37 vm1 crond[12493]: (CRON) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at computer's startup.)
Oct 14 09:59:01 vm1 CROND[12504]: (root) CMD (. ~/.restic.env ; /usr/local/bin/restic backup --files-from=/root/restic.files --tag automated 2>> ~/restic.err >> ~/restic.log)
Oct 14 10:00:01 vm1 CROND[12529]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 14 10:01:01 vm1 CROND[12550]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 14 10:01:01 vm1 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[12550]: starting 0anacron
Oct 14 10:01:01 vm1 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[12561]: finished 0anacron
Oct 14 10:01:01 vm1 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[12550]: starting mcelog.cron
Oct 14 10:01:01 vm1 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[12569]: finished mcelog.cron
```

Where did I make a mistake by setting up the cron job?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. The correct path was /usr/bin/restic and not /usr/bin/local/restic